# Drawing random paths in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, paths

I am looking for a way to draw with TikZ something that looks like a random path.

Here is an inspiration:

[image: example]

Is it possible to have TikZ generate something that would be similar to a random path instead of manually choosing points to connect together?

Thanks!

P.S. This question falls into a more general question (that does not necessarily needs to be answered): is there a (meta-)way to use TikZ to draw diagrams as they would appear on a chalkboard during a class. I mean TikZ generates very professional looking diagrams, but it's hard to draw a "random" curve just to express some notion, or draw a "random" diagram or "random" example to explain a notion.

Comment: I guess that one of the problems with this is that things that _look_ random often aren't!  With the corollary that if something is truly random, it may not _look_ "random" to Joe Reader (or Jo Seminar-Audience).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an example taken directly from the pgf manual:

```
 \pgfmathsetseed{1}
 \foreach \col in {black,red,green,blue}
 {
   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=10pt,y=10pt,ultra thick,baseline,line cap=round]
     \coordinate (current point) at (0,0);
     \coordinate (old velocity) at (0,0);
     \coordinate (new velocity) at (rand,rand);
     \foreach \i in {0,1,...,100}
     {
       \draw[\col!\i] (current point) 
       .. controls ++([scale=-1]old velocity) and
                    ++(new velocity) .. ++(rand,rand)
          coordinate (current point);
       \coordinate (old velocity) at (new velocity);
       \coordinate (new velocity) at (rand,rand);
     }
   \end{tikzpicture}
 }
```

It is at the beginning of the Part VI: Mathematical and Object Oriented Engines.  The whole section on mathematical engine is what you want to read if you want to do random drawing in tikz.

Comment: Thanks for referencing, I forgot to look it up first. :-S

Answer (score 21):

A few weeks back, I was attending a course on polymers, so I threw together a quick [package to draw randomwalks](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/randomwalk/). For a path that looks like the one you describe, the parameters below should be ok:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{randomwalk}
\begin{document}
 \framebox{\RandomWalk {number = 300, length = 2pt, 
     angles = {0,10,20,50,-10,-20,-50}, degree, angles-relative}}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the code above.]

If you need additionnal features, I can try to add them.

Comment: Looks very interesting. Can you add an image? (I don't want to bother installing your package at the moment.)

Comment: @Hendrik: I just uploaded an example of the result of the code above.

Comment: This is great. I don't need to use this package, however an idea for something you could add would be depth-cued 3D random walks - that is, vary the x and y coordinates by their position in the figure, and cue z by varying the opacity / white balance of the line as if it's fading in or out of distance fog.

Comment: @eutactic: I'll think about that. But I need to learn a bit more TikZ first `;-)`.

Comment: I just happened across a [gallery](http://www.piprime.fr/developpeur/asymptote/surveys-asy/random-walk-asy-3d/?posts_per_page=-1)  of 3D random walks in various styles achieved with Asymptote. You may find them interesting.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `random` function, which generates a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1, and use it to define the direction and distance of line segments (or any other parameter of your drawing). The seed can be set using `\pgfmathsetseed`. You can achieve something quite akin to the drawing you linked to using the `[round corners]` style in the `\draw` command:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [rounded corners] (0,0)
  \foreach \i in {1,...,300} {
    -- ++(rnd*360:rnd)
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: random smoothed walk]

I don't know about the "natural-looking" drawings, though. I think that's a very difficult task for any programmatic drawing program, because you'd need to set quite a few constraints to stop the picture from going totally random.

Comment: Would there be a reason why it tells me "Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'random'" ?

Comment: Should `random` not be `rand`?

Comment: @Matthew: `rand` is between -1 and 1, `random` is between 0 and 1, but maybe that's a function that's been added in one of the more recent versions of TikZ.

Comment: @Alex: `random` might be a function that's not included in your version of TikZ. `rand` should work in this case as well.

Comment: @Alex: in my manual (2.10) it documents the usage of `rnd` or `random()` to get a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1, but not `random` by itself.  I wondered if that were the cause of Alex's error.

Comment: @Matthew: You're right, `rnd` is the correct way to do it. I've changed my answer accordingly. `random` without the parentheses is not documented, but worked fine for me (while, interestingly, `random()` does not).

Comment: Actually the seed is set by `pgfmathsetseed`

Comment: @Ger: You're right, fixed the typo.