# TikZ: Curve through specified points

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,scopes,calc,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
            \matrix (A5) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
                {7}  \& {2} \& {7} \& {7} \& {2} \& {8}\\
            };
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \matrix (B5) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]A5-1-1.south) [anchor=B5-1-1.north, matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
            {12} \& {7} \& {2} \& {7} \& {2} \& {8}\\
        };
    \end{scope}
    \path[draw] (A5-1-3.north west) -- (A5-1-4.north east) -- (B5-1-4.south east) -- (B5-1-4.south west) -- (A5-1-3.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here `\path[draw]` groups 7s of the two matrices together. Is there any way to group them with a more "curvy" curve? i.e. by some curve that doesn't look so regular.

[image: result]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this (note that I replaced your last coordinate by `-- cycle`)?

```
\draw [rounded corners=5pt]
  (A5-1-3.north west) -- (A5-1-4.north east) --
  (B5-1-4.south east) -- (B5-1-4.south west) -- cycle;
```

[image: round corners]

or more like this?

```
\draw
  [decoration={random steps,segment length=6pt,amplitude=1.5pt},
   decorate, rounded corners=2pt]
  (A5-1-3.north west) -- (A5-1-4.north east) --
  (B5-1-4.south east) -- (B5-1-4.south west) -- cycle
```

[image: zig-zag]

I’d prefer the first one because it looks better matching to the style of printed text. The latter seems like some one attacked your paper ;-)

PS: I don’t know why the zig zag curve doesn’t close itself maybe one can fix this, please?

Comment: Instead of `cycle` you can just repeat the first point to close the shape.

Comment: @percusse: Yeah I know but that doesn’t give a rounded corner at this point too.

Answer (score 12):

Replace the last line with:

```
\draw plot [smooth cycle,tension=0.3] coordinates {(A5-1-3.north west)  (A5-1-4.north east)  (B5-1-4.south east) (B5-1-4.south west)};
```

The option `smooth cycle` results in the points to be closed using a smooth curve (so you don't include the initial point twice as was the case in your original code).

The `tension` can be adjusted to suit. Also refer to [Easy curves in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,scopes,calc,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
            \matrix (A5) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
                {7}  \& {2} \& {7} \& {7} \& {2} \& {8}\\
            };
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \matrix (B5) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]A5-1-1.south) [anchor=B5-1-1.north, matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
            {12} \& {7} \& {2} \& {7} \& {2} \& {8}\\
        };
    \end{scope}
\draw plot [smooth cycle,tension=0.3] coordinates {(A5-1-3.north west)  (A5-1-4.north east)  (B5-1-4.south east) (B5-1-4.south west)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't look too good for the start/end point, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Have adjusted the code to fix this. Basically use `smooth cycle` and only list each point once.

Comment: Great, `smooth cycle` had escaped my attention.