# How to draw a closed curve around a set of points/nodes keeping a minimum distance?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I basically want to achieve the same thing in Tikz as Ilonpilaaja in the following question:

- [TikZ: Curve through specified points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40571/tikz-curve-through-specified-points)

However, I have to do this multiple times with nodes that are spread around more chaotically. I am not happy having to manually specify all the points the curve has to *pass through* (`X.south west`, `X.south east`, etc.). I'd rather specify the coordinates that it has to *pass some distance around*.

To put it another way: I'd be quite happy with a cycled path with `rounded corners`, but then I'd want specify the *center* for each 'corner arc' rather than the underlying 'sharp corner' points. One could be translated to the other, but as far as I can tell this would require tedious calculation of angles.

Is there a (simple) way to do this?

Comment: A picture (even if just a doodle) speaks louder than a thousand words...

Comment: the `hobby` package might be useful here- there are a few good demonstrations on this site, it's just a matter of some google fu :)

Comment: Could you add a MWE so that we don’t need to set up the nodes? A dirty trick would be to set the `outer sep` to `.5\pgflinewidth + <radius of corner arc>` so that the center of those arcs still lie on the outer border of the node path. — Another idea would be to find a node’s anchor that lies more away from other nodes to use as a connection.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [padded boundary of convex hull](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull) or [Hobby path realization in convex hull approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71638/13304)?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'll flag my question as a duplicate.

Comment: Interesting that my one vote wouldn't be enough to close my own question. I suppose once it is out there it is *everyone's question*. :-)

Comment: @mhelvens: you're welcome. I think users can always delete their own question (never tried, thus I'm not sure), but to close it 5 votes are necessary. Don't mind: it's not difficult to find them.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I didn't want to delete because my question may contain keywords that will make it easier for others to find.