# Structural analysis best package

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering

Which is the best package to draw up structural analysis problems. I need beam or truss, constraints, displacements, springs, loads, thermal actions and so on.

Something like this picture: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Truss_Structure_Analysis%2C_Full_Figure2.jpg

Comment: Can you provide an image (or a link to one image) showing exactly the kind of diagrams you are planning to draw?

Comment: @Umz: I think "structuralanalysis" is a very well done macro but has not spring or displacements so I'm look a little better or complete

Comment: @ marchetto, It has spring option in it. If you see its manual, although manual is in german but going through examples one can learn to create some usefull stuff. I am not sure what do you mean by displacements?I shall post a simple example and a bit more detail into an answer just for an introduction.@Gonzalo Medina I just try to put a simple example(from manual) and another worked out example to just elaborate OP, that it could be usefull.

Comment: @umz is there any English translation to that suggested style? The documentation is in German, to which I am not familiar with.

Comment: @marchetto I recently read the documentation of that style. It has the displacements loads in the pages 14 and 18 of the 2d documentation and springs in the page 10 of the documentation.

Comment: @Enthusiastic Student, as yet I do not know if a translated version of this document exists. I also don't understand German but words like hinge, point, beam etc are in english and going through  examples given in 2d document (3d version is also interesting!) one may figure out how to work with simple structures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since I could not include further detail in my comment, I post it in this section.

The tikz library `structuralanalysis` provides some basic structural stuff which can be usefull to create hinges, supports, beams etc. This library provides 10 different commands `\point`, `\beam`,`\support`,`\hinge`,`\load` or `\lineload` and `\temperature`, `\internalforces`,`\dimensioning`,`\influenceline` ,`\notation` and `\addon`. The author of the library has provided with 4 types of beams (by default), 6 supports, 5 hinges and 3 types of loads (moment and forces at a point) and 4 types of lineloads (distributed forces).
I just put a simple example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\point{a}{0}{0};
\point{fprime}{.15}{1}
\point{b}{-.5}{.12};
\point{c}{.5}{.12};
\point{d}{-.5}{.3};
\point{e}{.5}{.3}
\point{f}{0}{1};

\support{3}{a};
\hinge{1}{b}
\hinge{1}{c}
\beam{4}{d}{e}
\beam{4}{d}{f}
\beam{4}{f}{e}
\hinge{1}{f}
\point{g}{6}{1}
\beam{4}{fprime}{g}
\dimensioning{1}{fprime}{g}{2}[\SI{2}{\m}];
%\point{force}{-2}{1.5}
%\load{1}{f}[90]% uncomment to introduce vertical load at the hinge
%\notation{1}{force}{F=10KN}% Just to show the unit and magnitude of the hypothetical force
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output]

Note I worked out this simple support using the basic functions of the library. Spring is given bydefault. I show it below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\point{a}{0}{0};
\support{5}{a}[45];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output]

`[45]` is to rotate the spring. One can set it to `0` for no rotation. Offcourse further knowledge of TikZ would enhance one's capability to go deep, but as far as simple structures are concerned, this library is quite usefull in my opinion. For further references see the manual of this library available at [here](http://www.latex-community.org/pkg/TikZ%20Library%20for%20Structural%20Analysis.pdf). And you can download `.sty` file from [here](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/472-tikz-structural-analysis).

**EDIT** I also put the structure which you have shown in the link. One possible way to do that can be this (using the same library):

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \point{a}{0}{0};
    \point{first}{-1}{0}
    \notation{1}{first}{A};
    \support{1}{a}[0];
    \point{b}{8}{0}
    \beam{4}{a}{b}
    \dimensioning{1}{a}{b}{-2.5}[\SI{2}{\m}];
    \point{c}{8}{-1.5}
    \support{3}{c}
    \point{c2}{7.5}{-1.32}
    \hinge{1}{c2}
    \point{c3}{8.5}{-1.32}
    \hinge{1}{c3}
    \point{beam1}{7.55}{-1.15}
    \point{beam2}{8.55}{-1.15}
    \beam{4}{beam1}{beam2}
    \beam{4}{beam1}{b}
    \beam{4}{beam2}{b}
    \notation{1}{b}{B};
    \point{D}{4}{1.74};
    \notation{1}{D}{D};
    \beam{4}{a}{D}
    \beam{4}{D}{b}
    \dimensioning{2}{b}{D}{11}[$\sqrt{3}$];
    \dimensioning{3}{b}{D}{-2.5}[\SI{2}{\m}];
    \point{C}{8}{1.74}
    \notation{1}{C}{C}
    \beam{4}{D}{C}
    \beam{4}{C}{b}
    \dimensioning{3}{a}{D}{2.5}[\SI{2}{\m}];
    \dimensioning{1}{D}{C}{2.3}[\SI{2}{\m}];
    \point{f}{4}{2.5}
    \load{1}{f}[90]
    \point{force}{2}{2.7}
    \notation{1}{force}{$F=\SI{10}{\N}$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You should load `siunitx` and then use, say, `\notation{1}{force}{$F=\SI{10}{\N}$}`. (The same for the lengths.)

Comment: With "displacement" I mean imposed displacement. For example: a horizontal built in beam with a vertical imposed displacement at one edge deformates. The library structuralanalysis has not deformed beam

Comment: @  Svend Tveskæg, Thanks for pointing it out. I have just updated it.

Comment: I'll change your code for using `siunitx` a bit; it can be done in a 'better' way. (I hope you don't mind.)

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg, You are doing a favour by editing it. Thanks again!.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem of deformed beam due to imposed displacement or thermal action. Some idea?

Comment: @ marchetto, with Tikz you can draw a curve, which can show the deformation of the beam. See this link:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz. Also, I  drew support B using beams(that was for example purpose only), whereas you can easily draw it with lines with thickness of your choice .

Comment: Can anyone answer this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561473/generating-structural-analysis-diagrams