# Correct way to make command defined in tikzpicture environment (in an example) available in all documents?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

The [wonderful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33610/49339) to the question [Easy curves in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz/33610#33610) shares some code that is defined inside a `tikzpicture` environment. I share the relevant portion of the answer here:

---

Here is a slightly modified version of the plothandler, which allows you to specify the first and last support point using the TikZ key `first support={<point>}` and `last support={<point>}`, where `<point>` can be any TikZ coordinate expression, such as`(1,2)`, `(1cm,2pt)`, `(A.south west)`, `([xshift=1cm] A.south west)` (thanks to Andrew Stacey's wonderful answer to [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz/33765#33765)).

By default, the points are assumed to refer to coordinates relative to the first/last point of the path. You can specify that the support points are given as absolute coordinates by using the keys `absolute first support`, `absolute last support`, or `absolute supports`.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    show curve controls/.style={
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            curveto code={
                \draw [blue, dashed]
                    (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
                    node [at end, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
                \draw [blue, dashed]
                    (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
                    node [at start, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
            }
        }, decorate
    }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}

\newif\iffirstsupportabsolute
\newif\iflastsupportabsolute

\tikzset{
    absolute first support/.is if=firstsupportabsolute,
    absolute first support=false,
    absolute last support/.is if=lastsupportabsolute,
    absolute last support=false,
    absolute supports/.style={
        absolute first support=#1,
        absolute last support=#1
    },
    first support/.code={
        \gettikzxy{#1}{\pgf@plot@firstsupportrelx}{\pgf@plot@firstsupportrely}
    },
    first support={(0pt,0pt)},
    last support/.code={
        \gettikzxy{#1}{\pgf@plot@lastsupportrelx}{\pgf@plot@lastsupportrely}
    },
    last support={(0pt,0pt)}
}

\def\pgf@plot@curveto@handler@initial#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
  \pgf@plot@first@action{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
  \xdef\pgf@plot@curveto@first{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}%
  \iffirstsupportabsolute
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@plot@firstsupportrelx%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@plot@firstsupportrely%
  \else
    \advance\pgf@xa by\pgf@plot@firstsupportrelx%
    \advance\pgf@ya by\pgf@plot@firstsupportrely%
  \fi
  \xdef\pgf@plot@curveto@firstsupport{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}%
  \global\let\pgf@plot@curveto@first@support=\pgf@plot@curveto@firstsupport%
  \global\let\pgf@plotstreampoint=\pgf@plot@curveto@handler@second%
}

\def\pgf@plot@curveto@handler@finish{%
  \ifpgf@plot@started%
    \pgf@process{\pgf@plot@curveto@second}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \iflastsupportabsolute
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@plot@lastsupportrelx%
      \pgf@ya=\pgf@plot@lastsupportrely%
    \else
      \advance\pgf@xa by\pgf@plot@lastsupportrelx%
      \advance\pgf@ya by\pgf@plot@lastsupportrely%
    \fi
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgf@plot@curveto@first@support}{\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}{\pgf@plot@curveto@second}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\coordinate (A) at (2,-1);

\draw [gray!50]  (-1,-0.5) -- (1.5,1) -- (3,0);
\draw [
    cyan,
    postaction=show curve controls
] plot [
    smooth, tension=2,
    absolute supports,
    first support={(A)},
    last support={(A)}] coordinates { (-1,-0.5) (1.5,1) (3,0)};

\draw [
    yshift=-3cm,
    magenta,
    postaction=show curve controls
] plot [
    smooth, tension=2,
    first support={(-0.5cm,1cm)},
    last support={(0.5cm,1cm)}] coordinates { (-1,-0.5) (1.5,1) (3,0)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I would like to make the commands defined between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` available in all my documents. What is the correct way for me to do so?

Comment: You can create a personal `sty` file and the you can load it using `\usepackage{}`. You can save it on the `tex` folder to be available for all users (or just save it on the same folder as your `tex` file).

Comment: put the commands without `\makeat...` in a file `mystuff.sty` and then use `\usepackage{mystuff}` whenever you need them

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does it matter though that (in the example) they are defined inside a `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: all the `\new...` commands are better outside anyway the only issue is the `tikzset` which would affect all tikzpictures I would guess if you don't want that it is best to make your package do `\newcommand\mytikzsetttings{\tikset...` then just use `\mytiksettings in teh tikzpicture that need this

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you convert your comments into an answer for this one?