# tikz node distance not measured by border but center

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

I have a pic element draw headphone, it works perfect but node distance is measured from center but not border as other nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1cm,
    box/.style = {draw, circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=4pt},
       headphone/.pic={
        \node[circle,fill={rgb,255 :red,220; green,150; blue,100},inner sep=0,anchor=center] (-outline) at (0,0) {};
        \begin{scope}[x={(-outline.east)},y={(-outline.north)},scale=2]
          \fill[white,rounded corners=1pt] ($(-40:.3)+(0,-0.2)$) -- ($(-40:.3)+(-0.15,-0.2)$) -- ($(-40:.3) + (-0.15,0)$) -- 
          (-40:.3) arc [start angle=-40,end angle=220, radius=0.3] --
          ++ (0.15,0) --++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.15,0) --
          (225:.35) arc [start angle=225,end angle=-45, radius=0.35] --cycle;
          \draw[draw={rgb,255 :red,220; green,150; blue,100}] (-40:.325) arc [start angle=-40,end angle=220, radius=0.325];
        \end{scope}}
    ]
    \draw[help lines] (-1,-3) grid (3,1);
    \node[box] (A) {A};
    \node[box,right=of A] (B) {B};
    \node[box,below=of B] (C) {C};
    \pic[left=1cm of C,minimum size=1cm] (D) {headphone};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It caused by the `anchor=center` parameter in `-outline` box, but if I remove that, the coordinate within the scope will not work.

Comment: In this case I would just do `\pic[minimum size=1cm] (D) at (A |- C) {headphone};` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to write `\node[anchor=east] (-outline) at (0,0) {};` it would put `(-outline.east)` at `(0,0)`, which in this case puts the center of the node at `(-.5,0)` in the pic coordinates. Since the origin of your pic is not at `(-outline.center)`, your vector arithmetic is off. You can fix it by shifting the scope to the correct origin before you scale it:

```
\begin{scope}[shift=(-outline),x={(-outline.east)},y={(-outline.north)},scale=2]
```

(and of course remove `anchor=center`).

[I also ought to point out that while you have gone to pains to make the headphones scale with the node, the `rounded corners` parameter does not scale. It actually seems pretty tricky to get it to do so.]

Comment: You are right, it works. any suggestion for rounded corner not work for scale issue?

Comment: I haven't seen any good way of getting `rounded corners` to scale. Most other ways of drawing curves will scale, though. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz) for some options.

Comment: Alternatively, Torbjørn T.'s solution will also scale correctly, since it's importing the compiled picture rather than rendering it again at at different size.

Comment: Yes, use `to [out=xx,in=xx]` will help improve. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In this case I would simply do

```
\pic[minimum size=1cm] (D) at (A |- C) {headphone};
```

avoiding the use of the `positioning` library altogether.

I could suggest a completely different approach to this though. First, make a new file `headphone.tex`, containing only the headphone symbol, however you like to draw it, e.g.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
       headphone/.pic={
        \node[circle,fill={rgb,255 :red,220; green,150; blue,100},inner sep=0,anchor=center] (-outline) at (0,0) {};
        \begin{scope}[x={(-outline.east)},y={(-outline.north)},scale=2]
          \fill[white,rounded corners=1pt] ($(-40:.3)+(0,-0.2)$) -- ($(-40:.3)+(-0.15,-0.2)$) -- ($(-40:.3) + (-0.15,0)$) -- 
          (-40:.3) arc [start angle=-40,end angle=220, radius=0.3] --
          ++ (0.15,0) --++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.15,0) --
          (225:.35) arc [start angle=225,end angle=-45, radius=0.35] --cycle;
          \draw[draw={rgb,255 :red,220; green,150; blue,100}] (-40:.325) arc [start angle=-40,end angle=220, radius=0.325];
        \end{scope}}
    ]
    \pic[minimum size=1cm] (D) {headphone};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can then use a `path picture` to put this image on the background of a circular node, as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1cm,
    box/.style = {draw, circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=4pt},
    headphone/.style={
       circle,minimum size=#1,
       path picture={\node [anchor=center] at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[width=#1]{headphone}};}
    },
    headphone/.default=1cm
    ]
    \draw[help lines] (-1,-3) grid (3,1);
    \node[box] (A) {A};
    \node[box,right=of A] (B) {B};
    \node[box,below=of B] (C) {C};
    \node[headphone,left=1cm of C] (D) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of last code block]

Comment: Thanks, never know `path picture` usage before! great idea.emma's suggestion works for my case also.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit tweak Torbjørn T.'s answer,`path picture` is awesome for this case w/o new tex file:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1cm,
    box/.style = {draw, circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=4pt},
   headphone/.style = {path picture={
       \node[circle,fill={rgb,255 :red,220; green,150; blue,100},anchor=center] (-outline) {};
       \begin{scope}[x={(-outline.east)},y={(-outline.north)}]
             \fill[white] (-50:.5) arc [start angle=-50,end angle=230, radius=.5] to[out=45,in=135] ++(0.2,0) to[out=-45,in=45] ++(0,-0.2) to[out=-135,in=-45] ++(-0.2,0) to[out=135,in=-90] (230:.55) arc [start angle=230,end angle=-50, radius=.55] to[out=-90,in=45] ($(-50:.5)+(0,-.2)$) to[out=-135,in=-45] ($(-50:.5)+(-.2,-.2)$) to[out=135,in=-135] ($(-50:.5)+(-.2,0)$) to[out=45,in=135] cycle; 
       \end{scope}
                }}
    ]
    \draw[help lines] (-1,-3) grid (3,1);
    \node[box] (A) {A};
    \node[box,right=of A] (B) {B};
    \node[box,below=of B] (C) {C};
    \node[left=1cm of C,minimum size=1cm,headphone] (D) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]