# Network diagram with flow on Latex

Tags: diagrams, flow-charts

I would like to be able to draw a nice diagram in one of my paper, however, I am having some trouble finding either a tutorial that explains to me how to do a diagram along the lines of the one I have in mind. The figure 1 in this paper is more or less what I am looking for https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.05398.pdf. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement such a diagram in latex? I have checked on http://www.texample.net/tikz/ but couldn't find anything relevant sadly.

[image]

Comment: recently i saw here some good souls who offer service "i-will-do-it-for-you" ,  maybe someone will raw this image for you ... however, you should show us, what you do so far and where you stack in this. in normal circumstances here is not offer mentioned service. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: As a general note, if you only look for tutorials/examples that are nearly identical to what you're after, there will in most cases be little or no info. So don't look just for that, look also for diagrams with similar *concepts*, e.g. circles with lines drawn between them. There is an example of exactly that in the second tutorial of the TikZ manual as well (chapter 3), which would probably be beneficial to go through. If you do that you should be able to do most of that diagram yourself I would think. Then ask about the parts that you are unable to figure out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My impression is that the image has been produced wit an external tool.

Comment: Yeah, of course, my point is mostly to get a tutorial. I think the main issue is how to draw the flow lines. The rest can be done using traditional tutorials.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Funnily enough, I was actually checking this exact chapter today :-).

Comment: @egreg Interesting, do you have any idea what tool would have been used to construct such diagrams?

Comment: If you download the source from arXiv, you discover that the picture is an external PDF file, which says to have `Mac OS X 10.11.6 Quartz PDFContext` as producer. No idea what tool was used.

Comment: One possible method for the flow lines could be https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz/33610#33610

Comment: @egreg Well that solves the issue and explains why I was not able to find anything on the many tutorial I went through. By the way, I had no idea, you could download the source from arXiv, this is a great piece of info. Thank you!

Comment: After a bit of research, I realized that draw.io had a very easy interface for curving lines. Less elegant but more efficient! Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sf]
\node[draw,circle,label=below:$n_1$] (n1) at ({-sqrt(3)},-1){};
\node[draw,circle,label=above:$n_2$] (n2) at (0,2){};
\node[draw,circle,label=below:$n_3$] (n3) at ({sqrt(3)},-1){};
\node[draw,circle,label=above:$s_2$,label=below:$d_1$] (s2) at (-4,3){};
\node[draw,circle,label=above:$s_3$] (s3) at (4,3){};
\node[draw,circle,label=above:$s_1$] (s1) at (-4,-2){};
\node[draw,circle,label=above:$d_3$,label=below:$d_2$] (s4) at (4,-2){};
\draw[thick,-latex] (n1) -- (n2);
\draw[thick,-latex] (n1) -- (n3);
\draw[thick,-latex] (n2.-45) -- (n3.105);
\draw[thick,-latex] (n3.135) -- (n2.-75);
\draw[thick,-latex] (s1) -- (n1);
\draw[thick,-latex] (n3) -- (s4);
\draw[thick,-latex] (s3) -- (n2);
\draw[thick,-latex] (s2.-15) -- (n2.135);
\draw[thick,-latex] (n2.165) -- (s2.-45);
\draw[green,dashed,thick,-latex] (-4.2,3.2) .. controls ($(n2)+(0.5cm,1cm)$) and
($(n3)-(1cm,2cm)$) .. (4.2,-2.2);
\node at (-3,3.5) {Flow 2}; 
\draw[blue,dashed,thick,-latex] (4.2,3.2) .. controls ($(n2)+(0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) and
($(n3)-(0cm,0cm)$) .. (4.2,-2);
\node at (-3,1) {Flow 1}; 
\draw[red,dashed,thick,-latex] (-4.2,-2.2) .. controls ($(n1)-(0.15cm,0cm)$) and
($(n2)-(0.2cm,0cm)$) .. (-4.2,3.2);
\node at (3,1) {Flow 3}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]