# tikz - how to bend straight lines in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

So I'm trying to plot a graph with routes. I have two questions:

1. How can I bend the lines? I would like the 9->4 to go around node 7.
2. How can I change the names of the nodes? I want node 9 to be called "0".

Is the method I chose to simple to make these changes?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.1,vertex/.style={draw,circle}, arc/.style={draw,thick,->}]
\foreach [count=\i] \coord in {(40,30),(90,10),(20,70),(100,20),(90,20),(70,30),(70,40),(10,70),(50,50)}{
    \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
}
\foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0}}{
    \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
        \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc] (p\r) edge (p\c);
        \fi
    }
} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex StackExchange. See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz) for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit : Added an even simpler syntax with the graphs library

It should be noted that there is a typographical error in the manual 3.0.1a, the `use existing nodes` key must be written in the plural (with an s to node) and not in the singular as in the manual.
I just created a ticket for this: [#494 typographical error `use existing node`](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/494/)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,every node/.style={draw,circle}]
\foreach \coord [count=\i from 0]  in {(5,5),(4,3),(9,1),(2,7),(10,2),(9,2),(7,3),(7,4),(1,7)}{
    \node (p\i) at \coord {\i};
}
\graph [use existing nodes,edges={thick}]
{
p0->p8->p3->p1->p0->[bend left]p4->p2->p5->p6->p7->p0;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Old answer:

I coded your figure in a simpler way using the native possibilities of the `foreach` loop and the `chains` library.

It is possible to make only one loop: the one that defines the nodes. To make node 9 `(5,5)` named 0, simply place it at the beginning of the foreach and start the count at zero.

```
\foreach \coord [count=\i from 0]  in {(5,5),(4,3),(9,1),(2,7),(10,2),(9,2),(7,3),(7,4),(1,7)}{
    \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
}
```

Then with the chains library to connect the nodes with arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,scale=1,every node/.style={draw,circle}, every join/.style={draw,thick,->}]
\foreach \coord [count=\i from 0]  in {(5,5),(4,3),(9,1),(2,7),(10,2),(9,2),(7,3),(7,4),(1,7)}{
    \node (p\i) at \coord {\i};
}
\chainin (p0);
\chainin (p8)[join];
\chainin (p3)[join];
\chainin (p1)[join];
\chainin (p0)[join];
\chainin (p4)[join=with p0 by {bend left}];
\chainin (p2)[join];
\chainin (p5)[join];
\chainin (p6)[join];
\chainin (p7)[join];
\chainin (p0)[join];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chaine]

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I had to rescale your coordinates to avoid `dimension too large` errors, yet the graph looks as if I had not done that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[vertex/.style={draw,circle}, arc/.style={draw,thick,->}]
\foreach [count=\i] \coord in {(4,3),(9,1),(2,7),(10,2),(9,2),(7,3),(7,4),(1,7),(5,5)}{
    \ifnum\i=9
    \node[vertex,alias=p0] (p\i) at \coord {0};
    \else
    \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
    \fi
}
\foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0}}{
    \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
        \ifnum\cell=1%
            \ifnum\r>\c
             \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{\r+\c*10}
             \ifnum\itest=49
              \draw[arc] (p\r) edge[bend left] (p\c);
             \else
              \draw[arc] (p\r) edge (p\c);
             \fi
            \else
             \draw[arc] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        \fi
    }
} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]