# Making Half a ellipse dashed - Coloring and area of a cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm having some problems drawing ellipse in tikz.
Can someone help(show) me, how I can make a graph like this?

[image: The graph]

I hope someone. could lead me on the way.

1. I can not find out to make some area a color, like between "a" and "b".
2. And the cylinder between "x_0" and "x" with the Oblique lines.
3. I can not find out to make half of the ellipse dashed like around "a"

My code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0,45\textwidth}\centering
        %\vspace{1cm}
        \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.55,0.55,0.9}
        \definecolor{gitter}{rgb}{0.65,0.65,0.65}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm, scale=1] 
            %\draw [color=gitter, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] (-5,-1) grid (5,10);  % Grid område
            \draw[->,color=black, line width=1pt] (-5,0) -- (15,0);    %X-akse
            %\draw[color=black] (-2,0) node[below] {\fontsize{7}{7}$\textbf{-2}$};  % -2 på xaksen
            \draw[color=black] (10,-0.4) node[below] {\fontsize{12}{12}$\textbf{b}$};  % b på xaksen
            \draw[color=black] (-3,-0.4) node[below] {\fontsize{12}{12}$\textbf{a}$};  % a på xaksen
            \draw[color=black] (15,0) node [anchor=west] {\fontsize{7}{7} \text{(1)}}; %Aksenanvn
            \draw[->,color=black, line width=1pt] (0,-10) -- (0,10);    %Y-akse
            \draw[color=black] (0,11.3) node [anchor=north] {\fontsize{7}{7} \text{(2)}}; % Aksenavn
            \clip(-5,-10) rectangle (15,10);
            \draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-5:15, line width=1pt, color=blue] plot(\x,{0.002*(\x)^3-0.02*(\x)+0.25*(\x)+4});
            \draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-3:10, line width=1pt, color=blue] plot(\x,{-0.002*(\x)^3+0.02*(\x)-0.25*(\x)-4});
            \draw[color=red,line width=1pt] (10,0) ellipse (0.5cm and 4.1cm); %grænse b
            \draw[color=red,line width=1pt] (-3,0) ellipse (0.5cm and 1.6cm); %Grænse a
            \draw (6,0) ellipse (0.5cm and 2.9cm);
            \draw (2,0) ellipse (0.5cm and 2.9cm);
            \draw (2,5.812) -- (6,5.812);
            \draw (2,-5.812) -- (6,-5.812);
            \draw[-,color=black,dashed, line width=1pt] (6,5.812) -- (6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not setting the font size explicitly, but use e.g. `\large` or variants. -not setting line width explicitly, but use `thick` or variants. -not using `color=black` as black is default color. `ellipse` always draws a full ellipse to draw a part, you can use `arc`. To `\fill` an area, it needs to be a fully closed curve. -first make a closed curve with `\draw` and then replace `\draw` with `\fill`. Here is a start:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {(1)};
   \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {(2)};
   \draw[color=red!80!black] (-1,0.4) arc [x radius=0.2, y radius=0.4, start angle=90, end angle=270];
   \draw[color=red!80!black, densely dotted] (-1,0.4) arc [x radius=0.2, y radius=0.4, start angle=90, end angle=-90];
   \draw (-1,-0.2) node {a};
   \draw[color=red!80!black] (3,0) ellipse [x radius=0.2, y radius=1];
   \draw (3,-0.2) node {b};
   \draw[blue, thick] (-1.4,0.3) to[out=10, in=190] (-1,0.4) to[out=10, in=210] (3,1) to[out=30, in=240] (4,1.5);
   \fill[red!50!yellow, opacity=0.5] (-1,-0.4) arc [x radius=0.2, y radius=0.4, start angle=-90, end angle=-270] to[out=10, in=210] (3,1) arc [x radius=0.2, y radius=1, start angle=90, end angle=-90] to[out=150, in=-10] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Hey, and thank you so far.
What does it mean when you write fx
[out=10, in=190]

Comment: `\draw (0,0) to[out=10, in=190] (1,1);` makes a curve going from (0,0) to (1,1). Leaving (0,0) at an angle of 10 deg and going into (1,1) at an angle of 200. You can read about different ways of making curves in TikZ including `to` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz

Comment: 190 - not 200..