# How to draw an eight contour

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a contour used in some exercises related to complex integration called eight contour, just like in the following image. The main problem for me is to get the shape around the auto-intersection. Have a nice week!

[image]

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz) about drawing curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example how you can do it in TIKZ only:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}]  
        (-1,0) to[out=90, in=125, looseness=2] (1,0) to[out=-55, in=-90, looseness=2] (2.5,0);
        
        \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}] 
        (-1,0) to[out=-90, in=-125, looseness=2] (1,0) to[out=55, in=90, looseness=2] (2.5,0);
        
        \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,-2) -- (0,4);
        \draw[stealth-stealth] (-2,0) -- (4,0);
        \filldraw [color=blue!50] (0,0) circle (2pt);
        \filldraw [color=blue!50] (2,0) circle (2pt);

        
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need