# Brownian Motion

Tags: tikz-pgf

everybody! I need your help, I'm struggling with the visualization of the Brownian motion and would like to reproduce the following graph:

[image]

I have already found a similar topic ([How to draw Brownian motions in tikz/pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59926/how-to-draw-brownian-motions-in-tikz-pgf)) but I dont know how to set the upper and the lower bound on the y-axis; I basically need a constrained random walk. If somebody could help me with that graph, I would be very grateful!

Comment: The code from [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59934/2552) allows you to constrain the random walk.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it helps! We'll probably close this question as a duplicate then.