# Annote a trajectory of a brownian motion

Tags: tikz-pgf, randomwalk

How can I have this

[image: Trajectory I want]

I've seeen on Stack various examples of a simulation of a brownian motion but I want to have exactly this trajectory

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Also, though I am far from being an expert on brownian motion, I am not sure that an *exact* Brownian motion can be reproduced, especially based on a picture of a hand written graph. You might want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125671/brownian-motion-with-drift