# Complex Venn diagram using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am reproducing Venn diagrams using TikZ but one of them is quite complicated (see fig.11 on p.15 attached).
Do you have suggestions?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you. And the signature is considered to be there (flair in the bottom right corner).

Comment: To be honest, I would never call fig.11 a Venn diagram, looks more like an amoeba. Perhaps you should use [Voronoi diagrams](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=voronoi+diagram) instead if your ultimate goal is reproduce the figure.

Comment: It is the irregular shapes that are probably the most challenging to draw in fig.11. I would start with filling [random paths in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11680/drawing-random-paths-in-tikz) The coloring can be dealt with by carefully using layers of `fill` with appropriate `opacity`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about essentially 'do this for me'.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I asked for suggestions. I did not ask the community to 'do this for me'. Perhaps because of my lack of experience I did not use the right words or did not give enough elements to say what is my problem. Should I rephrase my question? Thanks.