# Circle made up of a looping squiggly line

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to create the following kind of diagram using TikZ/PGF:

[image: Mumford style generic point diagram]

In words: a circle made up from a thick "random" squiggle.

This squiggle style comes from David Mumford in his description of generic points of schemes. Another example is:

[image: another generic point diagram]

The closest existing answer to what I want is in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11682/79106), but it is still considerably different. Specifically I want it to loop back on itself. To be able to easily control the density and width of the circle would be even better. Drawing a dot in the middle is not the important part, though.

Comment: what do you mean considerably different? We can't match a random path.

Comment: I mean that it does not loop back on itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one possible TikZ solution :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  % create \n random points around the circle with radious 5
  \def\n{50}
  \xdef\pts{}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{
    \xdef\pts{\pts ({\i/\n*360}:{5+rnd})}
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %draw random curve with some tension
    \draw[red, thick, smooth, tension=10] plot coordinates {\pts}--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you., this was very helpful. I got the nicest looking solution from this method out of all the three answers given.

Comment: @nobody you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 23):

## Squiggle

The following example draws the squiggle with randomness in the polar
coordinate system. It draws twelve circles with 500 points. Each point is
specified as polar coordinates. The radius is allowed in the range half to
one and a half radius. The angle can up to ten degrees in the forward or
backward direction. Changing the parameters allow the configuration of the
"squiggleness".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\radius{2cm}
  \pgfmathsetseed{1000}
  \draw
    plot[
       smooth cycle,
       samples=500,
       domain=0:360*12,
       variable=\t,
    ]
      (\t + rand*10:{\radius*(1 + rand*.5)})
  ;
  \fill circle[radius=1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Example with more clear parametrization and the middle dot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\InnerRadius{1cm}
  \def\OuterRadius{3cm}
  \def\PointsPerCircle{30}
  \def\NumOfCircles{15}
  \def\DeltaAngle{10}
  \pgfmathsetseed{2000}
  \draw[]
     plot[
       smooth cycle,
       samples=\PointsPerCircle*\NumOfCircles + 1,
       domain=0:360*\NumOfCircles,
       variable=\t,
    ]
      ( \t + rand*\DeltaAngle:
        {\InnerRadius + random*(\OuterRadius-\InnerRadius)})
  ;
  \fill circle[radius=1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Line

The following example makes a suggestion for the second example.
The line moves from left to right with random deltas in *x* direction (forward and backward). Both the random x-deltas and the random amplitude are modeled using the sin<sup>2</sup> function in the domain 0 to 180. Thus the amplitude reaches the larges values in the middle.

The distances of the point before follow a geometric series.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[radius=1mm]
    \foreach \prim [count=\i] in {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, {}, {}, {}, {}} {
      ({\i*1.8 - \i*(\i-1)*.5*0.175}, 0) circle[]
      node[below=1mm] (p\prim) {\prim}
    }
    ++(1mm, 0) coordinate (endofline)
    ++(25mm, 0) coordinate (end)
  ;
  \pgfmathsetseed{2000}
  \draw[semithick]
    (0, 0) -- (endofline)
    [shift=(endofline)]
    -- plot[
      smooth,
      tension=1.8,
      variable=\t,
      samples=140,
      domain=0:180,
    ]
      ({\t*25mm/180 + rand*sin(\t)*sin(\t)*3.5mm}, {sin(\t)*sin(\t)*rand*4mm})
    -- (end)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result line]

### Line with label for the "fuzzy" point

A label "generic point" can be put below the "fuzzy" point with the usual
TikZ means (`\node`, ...). The following example measures the bounding box
for the line (without labels) to get the lower right coordinate for placing
the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[radius=1mm]
    \foreach \prim [count=\i] in {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, {}, {}, {}, {}} {
      ({\i*1.8 - \i*(\i-1)*.5*0.175}, 0) circle[]
      node[below=1mm] (p\prim) {\prim}
    }
    ++(1mm, 0) coordinate (endofline)
    ++(25mm, 0) coordinate (end)
  ;
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \pgfmathsetseed{2000}
    \draw[semithick]
      (0, 0) -- (endofline)
      [shift=(endofline)]
      -- plot[
        smooth,
        tension=1.8,
        variable=\t,
        samples=140,
        domain=0:180,
      ]
        ({\t*25mm/180 + rand*sin(\t)*sin(\t)*3.5mm}, {sin(\t)*sin(\t)*rand*4mm})
      -- (end)
      (current bounding box.south west) coordinate (LowerLeft)
      (current bounding box.north east) coordinate (UpperRight)
    ;
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \path
    (LowerLeft) (UpperRight) % update bounding box
    (LowerLeft -| UpperRight) node[below left, yshift=1mm] {generic point}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old answer. May I ask if it is also possible to label the 'fuzzy' point in the final picture, the way it has been labled as 'generic point' in the picture that OP posted?

Comment: @Mark See updated answer.

Answer (score 14):

This doesn't use `Tikz`, but here is a solution in `asymptote`.

```
unitsize(1inch);

int numPoints = 150;
path p;
for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
{
    p = p..dir(i*360.0/numPoints)+scale(0.25)*(unitrand()-0.5, unitrand()-0.5);
}
p = p..cycle;

dot((0,0), 4+black);
draw(unitcircle, 1+green);
draw(p);
dot(p, 2+red);
```

[image]