# Draw a random path with arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I looked up how to draw a random path in tikz [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11680/drawing-random-paths-in-tikz). I came up with the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetseed{2}

  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5] (start) at (0,0) {};

  \draw (start.center)
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
      -- ++(-rnd,rnd)
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I would like to have arrow tips for every segment of the resulting path. Adding `[->]` to the draw operation only adds a tip at the final segment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetseed{2}

  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5] (start) at (0,0) {};

    \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
        \node (end) at ($(start)+(-rnd,rnd)$) {};
        \draw[->] (start.center) -- (end.center);
        \node (start) at (end) {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not know you could *re*define nodes within tikz. Awesome :)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. However I want to limit the random path to certain range. For example the x-axis random range should be [0-5] and y-axis [3-15]. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Simply push the `\draw[->]` command inside the loop and make the current end point be the next start point by adding `coordinate(i)` at the end of each `\draw[->]` path. The initial `(i)` is of course taken as `(0,0)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetseed{2}

  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5] (start) at (0,0) {} coordinate (i);

  \foreach \i in {1,...,5} { 
    \draw[->] (i)  
      -- ++(-rnd,rnd) coordinate(i); 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]