# Brownian Motion in 2D space, adding drift and a second motion

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, paths

So I found this code from [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11680/drawing-random-paths-in-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1) forums:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{randomwalk}
\begin{document}
\framebox{\RandomWalk {number = 300, length = 2pt, 
angles = {0,10,20,50,-10,-20,-50}, degree, angles-relative}}
\end{document}
```

There are two things I would like to add but I have no idea how to make it work. First, I want to add a second particle that is moving around in this space, hopefully, a different color. Second, I want the particles to have a drift, the drift must not be large relative to the variance, so they can still move back and forth but there should nevertheless be a long-term direction that will be followed in the long term.